# What is the Font of the word 'BEST' on the magazine cover?

Tags: font-identification

I'm trying to figure out what is the font that the word 'BEST' is. If anybody has any idea that would be helpful. I've tried font recognition, but not coming back with any results. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The style you are looking for is "woodcut" the most often seen ones are Rosewood and Zebrawood, but there is HUGE variation.

Honestly, this has the look of a custom-made image. If I were to guess, the '5' is probably where they got the curl. The majority of the typeface is repetitions of 2 or 3 forms aka copy/paste/modify. The B, T and E are, at their core, slightly altered versions of each other.

Without having the font on hand, it would be faster to make 4 letters than find it IMO.

Comment: Looks like they might have used as a base a lighter variant of whatever the "THE ... ISSUE ... STOCKS THAT YIELD" font is, then traced it and adjusted it, copying, pasting and merging the added embellishments. The proportions look quite similar (taking into account that the non-modified version is bolder).

Comment: Good eye Horatio, this is custom made, as mentioned by the designer herself here; http://jessicahische.is/makingcomplexstuffagain  Lettering seems to be her thing :)